# How to program a NSOutlineView?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, plist, nsoutlineview

I am having trouble creating a NSOutlineView in Xcode 8 (Swift 3). I have a plist file with some information that I would like to present in an OutlineView. The plist file looks as following (example):

```
Root                      Dictionary    *(1 item)
    Harry Watson          Dictionary    *(5 items)*
        name              String        Harry Watson
        age               Int           99
        birthplace        String        Westminster
        birthdate         Date          01/01/1000
        hobbies           Array         *(2 items)*
            item 0        String        Tennis
            item 1        String        Piano
```

The OutlineView should look pretty similar, like follow:

```
name            Harry Watson
age             99
birthplace      Westminster
birthdate       01/01/1000
> hobbies       ...             (<- this should be expandable)
```

I already searched for NSOutlineView tutorials on Google, but everything I found was raywenderlich.com, so I read a bit but in my opinion it isn't that easy. 
So I am wondering whether you could help me with the exact example above and give me some code examples, especially regarding this function:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {}
```

I am not sure what to write in there.

If you have any questions, let me know.

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: @ElTomato Hey, thanks for your comment - what do you mean? That is my own example!?! Could you help me if you think it's easy? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Willeke Well, I rebuilt the example on [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123463/nsoutlineview-macos-tutorial) and then tried it myself, but I still have difficulties to understand the whole thing.

Comment: @Willeke Hey, I now edited my question a bit, I tried some stuff but still have difficulties with the delegate function I mentioned in my question (at the very bottom). Could you help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well that's true. But I wouldn't compare a NSOutlineView with Rome. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I find Ray Wenderlitch's tutorials vary wildly in quality. The in-jokes, the verbosity, the step-by-step handholding that assumes you know nothing about Swift is just too nauseating to me. Here's a skinny tutorial which covers the basics of populating an outline view, manually and via Cocoa Bindings.

---

The key to understand `NSOutlineView` is that you must give each row a unique identifier, be it a string, a number or an object that represents the row. `NSOutlineView` calls it the `item`. Based on this `item`, you will query your data model to fill the outline view with data.

This answer presents 3 approaches:

1. Manual: doing everything yourself in the most basic way. It's a great introduction to learn how to interact with `NSOutlineView` but I don't recommend this for production code.
2. Streamlined: the outline view is still manually populated, but the approach is more elegant. This is what I use for my own production code.
3. Cocoa Binding: some magicky stuff left over from the golden days of Mac OS X. While very convenient, it's not the way of the future. Consider this an advanced topic

---

## 1. Populate the outline view manually

### Interface Builder Setup

We will use a very simple `NSOutlineView` with just two columns: Key and Value.

Select the first column and change its identifier to `keyColumn`. Then select the second column and change its identifier to `valueColumn`:

[image: Set the identifier for the Key column. Repeat for the Value column]

Set the identifier for the cell to `outlineViewCell`. You only need to do it once.
[image: Set the identifier for the cell]

### Code

Copy and paste the following to your `ViewController.swift`:

```swift
// Data model
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var birthPlace: String
    var birthDate: Date
    var hobbies: [String]
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!

    // I assume you know how load it from a plist so I will skip
    // that code and use a constant for simplicity
    let person = Person(name: "Harry Watson", age: 99, birthPlace: "Westminster",
                        birthDate: DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 1985, month: 1, day: 1).date!,
                        hobbies: ["Tennis", "Piano"])

    let keys = ["name", "age", "birthPlace", "birthDate", "hobbies"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        outlineView.dataSource = self
        outlineView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate {

    // You must give each row a unique identifier, referred to as `item` by the outline view
    //   * For top-level rows, we use the values in the `keys` array
    //   * For the hobbies sub-rows, we label them as ("hobbies", 0), ("hobbies", 1), ...
    //     The integer is the index in the hobbies array
    //
    // item == nil means it's the "root" row of the outline view, which is not visible
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        if item == nil {
            return keys[index]
        } else if let item = item as? String, item == "hobbies" {
            return ("hobbies", index)
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    // Tell how many children each row has:
    //    * The root row has 5 children: name, age, birthPlace, birthDate, hobbies
    //    * The hobbies row has how ever many hobbies there are
    //    * The other rows have no children
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        if item == nil {
            return keys.count
        } else if let item = item as? String, item == "hobbies" {
            return person.hobbies.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    // Tell whether the row is expandable. The only expandable row is the Hobbies row
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        if let item = item as? String, item == "hobbies" {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    // Set the text for each row
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        guard let columnIdentifier = tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue else {
            return nil
        }
    
        var text = ""
    
        // Recall that `item` is the row identiffier
        switch (columnIdentifier, item) {
        case ("keyColumn", let item as String):
            switch item {
            case "name":
                text = "Name"
            case "age":
                text = "Age"
            case "birthPlace":
                text = "Birth Place"
            case "birthDate":
                text = "Birth Date"
            case "hobbies":
                text = "Hobbies"
            default:
                break
            }
        case ("keyColumn", _):
            // Remember that we identified the hobby sub-rows differently
            if let (key, index) = item as? (String, Int), key == "hobbies" {
                text = person.hobbies[index]
            }
        case ("valueColumn", let item as String):
            switch item {
            case "name":
                text = person.name
            case "age":
                text = "\(person.age)"
            case "birthPlace":
                text = person.birthPlace
            case "birthDate":
                text = "\(person.birthDate)"
            default:
                break
            }
        default:
            text = ""
        }
    
        let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("outlineViewCell")
        let cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        cell.textField!.stringValue = text
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

### Result

[image: NSOutlineView]

---

## 2. A more streamlined approach

Set up your Storyboard as in #1. Then copy and paste the following code to your View Controller:

```swift
import Cocoa

/// The data Model
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var birthPlace: String
    var birthDate: Date
    var hobbies: [String]
}

/// Representation of a row in the outline view
struct OutlineViewRow {
    var key: String
    var value: Any?
    var children = [OutlineViewRow]()
    
    static func rowsFrom( person: Person) -> [OutlineViewRow] {
        let hobbiesChildren = person.hobbies.map { OutlineViewRow(key: $0) }
        return [
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Age", value: person.age),
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Birth Place", value: person.birthPlace),
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Birth Date", value: person.birthDate),
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Hobbies", children: hobbiesChildren)
        ]
    }
}

/// A listing of all available columns in the outline view.
///
/// Since repeating string literals is error prone, we define them in a single location here.
/// The literals must match the column identifiers in the Story Board
enum OutlineViewColumn: String {
    case key = "keyColumn"
    case value = "valueColumn"
    
    init?(tableColumn: NSTableColumn) {
        self.init(rawValue: tableColumn.identifier.rawValue)
    }
}


class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!
    
    let person = Person(name: "Harry Watson", age: 99, birthPlace: "Westminster",
                        birthDate: DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 1985, month: 1, day: 1).date!,
                        hobbies: ["Tennis", "Piano"])
    var rows = [OutlineViewRow]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.rows = OutlineViewRow.rowsFrom(person: self.person)
        outlineView.dataSource = self
        outlineView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    
    /// Return the item representing each row
    /// If item == nil, it is the root of the outline view and is invisible
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        switch item {
        case nil:
            return self.rows[index]
        case let row as OutlineViewRow:
            return row.children[index]
        default:
            return NSNull()
        }
    }
    
    /// Return the number of children for each row
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        switch item {
        case nil:
            return self.rows.count
        case let row as OutlineViewRow:
            return row.children.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    /// Determine if the row is expandable
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        switch item {
        case let row as OutlineViewRow:
            return !row.children.isEmpty
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
    
    /// Return content of the cell
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        guard let row = item as? OutlineViewRow,
              let column = OutlineViewColumn(tableColumn: tableColumn!)
        else {
            fatalError("Invalid row and column combination")
        }
        
        let text: String
        switch column {
        case .key:
            text = row.key
        case .value:
            text = row.value == nil ? "" : "\(row.value!)"
        }
        
        let identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("outlineViewCell")
        let view = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        view.textField?.stringValue = text
        
        return view
    }
}
```

---

## 3. Using Cocoa Bindings

Another way to populate the outline view is using Cocoa Bindings, which can significantly reduce the amount of code you need to write. However, consider Cocoa Bindings an advanced topic. When it works, it's like magic, but when it doesn't, it can be very hard to fix. Cocoa Bindings are not available on iOS.

### Code

For this example, let's up the ante by having the `NSOutlineView` showing details of multiple persons.

```
// Data Model
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var birthPlace: String
    var birthDate: Date
    var hobbies: [String]
}

// A wrapper object that represents a row in the Outline View
// Since Cocoa Binding relies on the Objective-C runtime, we need to mark this
// class with @objcMembers for dynamic dispatch
@objcMembers class OutlineViewRow: NSObject {
    var key: String                 // content of the Key column
    var value: Any?                 // content of the Value column
    var children: [OutlineViewRow]  // set to an empty array if the row has no children

    init(key: String, value: Any?, children: [OutlineViewRow]) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.children = children
    }

    convenience init(person: Person) {
        let hobbies = person.hobbies.map { OutlineViewRow(key: $0, value: nil, children: []) }
        let children = [
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Age", value: person.age, children: []),
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Birth Place", value: person.birthPlace, children: []),
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Birth Date", value: person.birthDate, children: []),
            OutlineViewRow(key: "Hobbies", value: nil, children: hobbies)
        ]
        self.init(key: person.name, value: nil, children: children)
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    let people = [
        Person(name: "Harry Watson", age: 99, birthPlace: "Westminster",
                birthDate: DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 1985, month: 1, day: 1).date!,
                hobbies: ["Tennis", "Piano"]),
        Person(name: "Shelock Holmes", age: 164, birthPlace: "London",
               birthDate: DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 1854, month: 1, day: 1).date!,
                hobbies: ["Violin", "Chemistry"])
    ]

    @objc lazy var rows = people.map { OutlineViewRow(person: $0) }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

### Interface Builder setup

In your storyboard:

- Add a Tree Controller from the Object Library
- Select the Tree Controller and open the Attributes Inspector (`Cmd + Opt + 4`). Set its Children key path to `children`.
- Open the Bindings inspector (`Cmd + Opt + 7`) and set up bindings for the IB objects as follow.

[image: Tree Controller's Attributes]

```
| IB Object       | Property           | Bind To         | Controller Key  | Model Key Path    |
|-----------------|--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------------|
| Tree Controller | Controller Content | View Controller |                 | self.rows         |
| Outline View    | Content            | Tree Controller | arrangedObjects |                   |
| Table View Cell | Value              | Table Cell View |                 | objectValue.key   |
| (Key column)    |                    |                 |                 |                   |
| Table View Cell | Value              | Table Cell View |                 | objectValue.value |
| (Value column)  |                    |                 |                 |                   |
```

(don't confuse Table View Cell with Table Cell View. Terrible naming, I know)

### Result

[image: NSOutline View with Cocoa Bindings]

You can use a `DateFormatter` for nicer date output in both approaches but that's not essential for this question.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! I will invest some time to understand all that, thanks for your help so far! ;-)

Comment: You need to turn this into a blog post and est up your own blog -called Skinny tutorials - this is epic.  Thanks for making it. I am just stuck on how to make the outline view selectable - ie add a checkbox in for each level of the hierarchy

Comment: @MobileBloke thanks for the compliment. You can ask a new question with what you have so far. I have made some refinements to my technique since answering this question

Comment: Awesome - I shared my approach here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484452/building-an-outline-view-with-check-marks

Comment: Strange: this works perfectly if I use it directly in an App. But if I load the view controller from a storyboard, expansion does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you connect the outlet?

Comment: Ah - turns out I was not resining the view controller. Works now.

Comment: @CodeDifferent, Can we add new column when outline view is already populated?

Comment: @LakshmiYadav yes you can, even though it's more complex. Please post a new question to get specific help for your problem

Comment: @CodeDifferent, I have created new question. you can find it at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65612055/12705149)

Answer (score 0):

A clear example and perfect as a start for working with a NSOutlineView.
As I work with a later Swift version, I had to change

`switch (columnIdentifier, item)`

to

`switch (columnIdentifier.rawValue, item)`.

Interface Builder also did the correct adjustments for setting

`let cell = outlineView.make(withIdentifier: "outlineViewCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView`

to

`let cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "outlineViewCell"), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView`