# Building an NSOutline view with Check marks

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I am looking to add checkboxes to NSOutlineview using the correct Apple recommended method - however its not clear from the documentation.

How do I add the behavour to allow users whereby if I click a parent checkbox, then it will select the children, and if I unclick it - it will deselect the children of that item?

edit: I have simplified my question and added image to make it clearer ( hopefully)

My Approach: 
I have been using the wonderful answer by Code Different to build an Outline view in my mac app. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384599/559760
- I chose to populate the NSoutLine view using a manual process instead of using CocoaBindings.

I added in a stack view including a check box which seems to be the right approach:

[image: Example with the checkbox]

My solution involves creating an array to hold the selected items in the viewcontroller and then creating functions for adding and removing

```
var selectedItems: [Int]?

@objc func cellWasClicked(sender: NSButton) {
    let newCheckBoxState = sender.state
    let tag = sender.tag
    switch newCheckBoxState {
    case NSControl.StateValue.on:
        print("adding- \(sender.tag)")
    case NSControl.StateValue.off:
        print("removing- \(sender.tag)")
    default:
        print("unhandled button state \(newCheckBoxState)")
    }
```

I identify the checkbutton by the tag that was assigned to the checkbox

Comment: Are you planning to populate the Outline View manually or with Cocoa Bindings?

Comment: What is the question, how to add a checkbox or how to select the checkbox of the children?

Comment: CodeDifferent - I updated it to say that I used manual process you recommended.  @Willeke - I edited it to make it clearer - thanks for the feedback - I am trying to use the correct method to select/ deselect the children nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In the interest of future Googlers I will repeat things I've written in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373039/how-to-program-a-nsoutlineview/45384599#45384599). The difference here is this has the extra requirement that a column is editable and I have refined the technique.*

---

The key to `NSOutlineView` is that you must give an identifier to each row, be it a string, a number or an object that uniquely identifies the row. `NSOutlineView` calls this the `item`. Based on this `item`, you will query your data model to populate the outline.

In this answer we will setup an outline view with 2 columns: an editable **Is Selected** column and a non-editable **Title** column.

---

## Interface Builder setup

- Select the first column and set its identifier to `isSelected`
- Select the second column and set its identifier to `title`

[image: set column identifier]

- Select the cell in the first column and change its identifier to `isSelectedCell`
- Select the cell in the second column and change its identifier to `titleCell`

[image: set cell identifier]

Consistency is important here. The cell's identifier should be equal to its column's identifier + `Cell`.

---

## The cell with a checkbox

The default `NSTableCellView` contains a non-editable text field. We want a check box so we have to design our own cell.

### CheckboxCellView.swift

```
import Cocoa

/// A set of methods that `CheckboxCelView` use to communicate changes to another object
protocol CheckboxCellViewDelegate {
    func checkboxCellView(_ cell: CheckboxCellView, didChangeState state: NSControl.StateValue)
}

class CheckboxCellView: NSTableCellView {

    /// The checkbox button
    @IBOutlet weak var checkboxButton: NSButton!

    /// The item that represent the row in the outline view
    /// We may potentially use this cell for multiple outline views so let's make it generic
    var item: Any?

    /// The delegate of the cell
    var delegate: CheckboxCellViewDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        checkboxButton.target = self
        checkboxButton.action = #selector(self.didChangeState(_:))
    }

    /// Notify the delegate that the checkbox's state has changed
    @objc private func didChangeState(_ sender: NSObject) {
        delegate?.checkboxCellView(self, didChangeState: checkboxButton.state)
    }
}
```

### Connecting the outlet

- Delete the default text field in the `isSelected` column
- Drag in a checkbox from Object Library
- Select the `NSTableCellView` and change its class to `CheckboxCellView`
- Turn on the Assistant Editor and connect the outlet

[image: set custom class and connect the outlet]

---

## The View Controller

And finally the code for the view controller:

```
import Cocoa


/// A class that represents a row in the outline view. Add as many properties as needed
/// for the columns in your outline view.
class OutlineViewRow {
    var title: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var children: [OutlineViewRow]

    init(title: String, isSelected: Bool, children: [OutlineViewRow] = []) {
        self.title = title
        self.isSelected = isSelected
        self.children = children
    }

    func setIsSelected(_ isSelected: Bool, recursive: Bool) {
        self.isSelected = isSelected
        if recursive {
            self.children.forEach { $0.setIsSelected(isSelected, recursive: true) }
        }
    }
}

/// A enum that represents the list of columns in the outline view. Enum is preferred over
/// string literals as they are checked at compile-time. Repeating the same strings over
/// and over again are error-prone. However, you need to make the Column Identifier in
/// Interface Builder with the raw value used here.
enum OutlineViewColumn: String {
    case isSelected = "isSelected"
    case title = "title"

    init?(_ tableColumn: NSTableColumn) {
        self.init(rawValue: tableColumn.identifier.rawValue)
    }

    var cellIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier {
        return NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(self.rawValue + "Cell")
    }
}


class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!

    /// The rows of the outline view
    let rows: [OutlineViewRow] = {
        var child1 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p1-child1", isSelected: true)
        var child2 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p1-child2", isSelected: true)
        var child3 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p1-child3", isSelected: true)
        let parent1 = OutlineViewRow(title: "parent1", isSelected: true, children: [child1, child2, child3])

        child1 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p2-child1", isSelected: true)
        child2 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p2-child2", isSelected: true)
        child3 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p2-child3", isSelected: true)
        let parent2 = OutlineViewRow(title: "parent2", isSelected: true, children: [child1, child2, child3])

        child1 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p3-child1", isSelected: true)
        child2 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p3-child2", isSelected: true)
        child3 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p3-child3", isSelected: true)
        let parent3 = OutlineViewRow(title: "parent3", isSelected: true, children: [child1, child2, child3])

        child3 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p4-child3", isSelected: true)
        child2 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p4-child2", isSelected: true, children: [child3])
        child1 = OutlineViewRow(title: "p4-child1", isSelected: true, children: [child2])
        let parent4 = OutlineViewRow(title: "parent4", isSelected: true, children: [child1])

        return [parent1, parent2, parent3, parent4]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        outlineView.dataSource = self
        outlineView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    /// Returns how many children a row has. `item == nil` means the root row (not visible)
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        switch item {
        case nil: return rows.count
        case let row as OutlineViewRow: return row.children.count
        default: return 0
        }
    }

    /// Returns the object that represents the row. `NSOutlineView` calls this the `item`
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        switch item {
        case nil: return rows[index]
        case let row as OutlineViewRow: return row.children[index]
        default: return NSNull()
        }
    }

    /// Returns whether the row can be expanded
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        switch item {
        case nil: return !rows.isEmpty
        case let row as OutlineViewRow: return !row.children.isEmpty
        default: return false
        }
    }

    /// Returns the view that display the content for each cell of the outline view
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        guard let item = item as? OutlineViewRow, let column = OutlineViewColumn(tableColumn!) else { return nil }

        switch column {
        case .isSelected:
            let cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: column.cellIdentifier, owner: self) as! CheckboxCellView
            cell.checkboxButton.state = item.isSelected ? .on : .off
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.item = item
            return cell

        case .title:
            let cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: column.cellIdentifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
            cell.textField?.stringValue = item.title
            return cell
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: CheckboxCellViewDelegate {
    /// A delegate function where we can act on update from the checkbox in the "Is Selected" column
    func checkboxCellView(_ cell: CheckboxCellView, didChangeState state: NSControl.StateValue) {
        guard let item = cell.item as? OutlineViewRow else { return }

        // The row and its children are selected if state == .on
        item.setIsSelected(state == .on, recursive: true)

        // This is more efficient than calling reload on every child since collapsed children are
        // not reloaded. They will be reloaded when they become visible
        outlineView.reloadItem(item, reloadChildren: true)
    }
}
```

## Result

[image: result]

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the efforts

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. Note, on Xcode 14.2/Swift 5, the line `case nil: return !rows.isEmpty` from `isItemExpandable` gives this warning: "Type 'Any' is not optional, value can never be nil; this is an error in Swift 6". I just removed it, it seems it will never be called, since `item` is indeed not an Optional.