# Create new column cell on button click outlineview

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an outlineview which displays list of data items. Attaching code and screenshot below. When I click on "Create New" button added to cell, I want to add a new item below selected cell.Any help?

[image: Outlineview screenshot]

```
@IBAction func CreateFolderClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let newMember = CubeData()
    let newIndex = selectedItemIndex
    let parent = foldersOutlineView.parent(forItem: foldersOutlineView.item(atRow: selectedRow))
    if let parentTemp = parent as? CubeData{
        let Temp = newMember.initWithNodeName(appName: "Testing", parent: parentTemp)
        newMember.addFolder(folder: Temp)
        foldersOutlineView.insertItems(at: newIndex, inParent: parentTemp.node, withAnimation: .slideDown)
        foldersOutlineView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Add the item to the data and insert an item in the outline view with `insertItems(at:inParent:withAnimation:)`.

Comment: @Willeke, I have appended new text into array and used `insertItems` method and then reloaded outlineview. But still no change in the outline view.

Apart from above steps, do we need to do any other steps?

Comment: No, you don't have to reload. Post your code please.

Comment: @Willeke, Updated code in the question.

Comment: What do `initWithNodeName`, `addFolder` and `parentTemp.node` do? At which child index do you want to insert the new item?

Comment: @Willeke, `CubeData` is an object class which contains all my data. `initWithNodeName` will convert text into type `Cubedata`. `addFolder` will add the new item into folders array of CubeData class.

Comment: I want to add a new element inside selected column cell.

Comment: Please describe how your code is not working. Is the data correct? Is the correct row inserted? Any errors or crashes?

Comment: The code is running without crash and errors but no change in the UI. Even with or without `reloadData()` no change in UI. @Willeke

Comment: At which parent and at which child index is the new item inserted in the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227037/discussion-between-lakshmi-yadav-and-willeke).

Comment: @Willeke, I am getting "ArrayIndexOutofRange." while using `insertItems`. Because my app is taking full child-parent data as a single array item. Thats why app is crashing in `outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?)` function.